# What should I use to fix this?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, pipe, pvc, irrigation

Pipe insulation keeps getting shredded by the weed wacker. I would like to fix the damaged insulation. PVC pipe is 1.5". I was going to buy some 1.5" pipe insulation and PVC tape. Also, going to buy a post shield to stop the weed eater from shredding this again. Are these the right products to use for this and best way to fix it?

- [insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-x-6-ft-Foam-Pipe-Insulation-ORP05812/204760811)
- [outdoor pipe tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/2-in-x-50-ft-20-Mil-Pipe-Wrap-Duct-Tape-53550/100179778)
- [post shields](https://postshields.com/collections/frontpage/products/round-post-shields)

[image]

Comment: The rubber stuff at 3-4X the price or so is legitimately "better" insulation, but if the cheap foam stuff is "good enough" then it's cheaper.

Comment: Be more accurate with the weed wacker.

Comment: Get a piece of 4" pvc. Cut it in half  or 2/3rds.  Fit it over the pipes like shin guards.  Problem solved.

Comment: remove the grass around the pipes, so that there is no need to approach with a weed trimmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use some galvanized sheet metal you can get at any hardware store.  Cut it to size and wrap it around the pipe and clamp it.

And it is a done deal.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a short piece of 3 inch PVC (Home centers usually have them in 2 ft sections) Cut it lengthwise then in halves and you will have 4 "shields of PVC to ziptie around the bottom of those pipes. The weed eater has no chance against that.

Comment: Thank you RMD. I think the problem or weak point with this will be the zipties. The weed whacker can chew up wood and I think plastic zipties won't last too long.